# Kubuntu 19.04 installer unusable at 800x600 in Virtualbox

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, kubuntu, display-resolution, 19.04

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 19.04 from the iso image in a VM running running under Virtualbox in Windows 10. Unfortunately the screen resolution during install seems to be fixed at 800x600 and the graphical installer is unsuable at that resolution:

[image]

Notice the "Next" button *outside* the screen?

Is there a way to either switch to a larger resolution from Virtualbox or make the installer usable at 800x600?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using a VGA graphics mode in virtual box (on your host), ie. check your windows 10 virtual box settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had seen [the same issue](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/72674-First-screen-in-Bionic-Beaver) trying to install Kubuntu 17.10 and 18.04 in VirtualBox.

The workaround in post #8 in the thread to which I linked above, is just to grab the title bar of the installer window and drag it to the left till the *next* or *continue* buttons are visible.